# How to clear all form input fields when clicking on a bootstrap tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have the following tabbed navigation:

```
<div>

    <ul class="nav nav-pills" >
        <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tasks" data-toggle="tab">Tasks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
   </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tasks">
        <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" id="search1" value="" class="form-control input-lg">
        </div>
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
        <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" id="search2" value="" class="form-control input-lg">
        </div>
        ....
    </div>
 </div>
```

I'm using the following code to clear all input fields when I click on a pill. However when I click on the current pill the input field doesn't clear? Example if I'm on the `tasks` pane and I click the `tasks` pill the following event doesn't seem to fire to cause all input fields to clear. They only clear when I cycle through the different pills.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
   $('.form-group input[type="text"]').val('');
});
```

How can I clear all input fields including when I click the current tab/pill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the event to "click"

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function (e) {
   $('.form-group input[type="text"]').val('');
});
```

Comment: How can you refresh the tabbed content aswell? I'm using the jquery searchable plugin https://github.com/stidges/jquery-searchable which filters a table. But when I set the input field to empty using the above jquery event, the filtered content doesn't seem to reappear?

Comment: $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function (e) {
   $('.form-group input[type="text"]').val('').trigger("keyup");
});